# Issue with Basic Image Magick Convert and Mogrify Functions

Tags: image, format, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am attempting to convert all .jpg images in a folder to .png format using Image Magick. This functionality is described as a feature of Image Magick [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) using the mogrify tool. Here's what I type into the command line, followed by the error:

```
C:\Users\holde\Desktop\Photos and Videos>magick mogrify -format jpg *.png
mogrify: unable to open image '*.png': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3527.
```

Any help is appreciated! If it's useful, I installed the Windows Binary release [from this page](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), and installed via the ImageMagick-6.9.12-32-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe executable on Windows 10.

Edit: Fixed, I had the syntax backwards. I should have used `mogrify -format png *.jpg` rather than `mogrify -format jpg *.png`
With this change, the operation now completes. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Looks like you may be missing the libpng delegate library. What do you get from `magick -version`. Also `magick -list format` and show us what you get for the line starting with PNG. It should look like `PNG* PNG       rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.6.37)`  The last part showing the libpng version is important.

Comment: Do you have PNG images in your directory?  The command you show tries to convert all PNGs in the directory to JPGs.

Comment: I do not see anything.  What does ```` mean?  If that is all you get from `magick -version` then there is a problem with your install.

Comment: Please post your answers by editing your original post, if you can. It can be formatted better there.

Comment: If you installed from the link you showed, then you installed Imagemagick 6 and not Imagemagick 7. Your command `magick mogrify ...` is wrong for Imagemagick 6. It should be `mogrify ...` without the leading `magick`.  Try your command again but without the leading `magick`

Comment: If you want to use Imagemagick 7, then install from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Answer (score 0):

Convert all from png to jpg

```bash
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```